# jQuery - Find Div That Contains part of ID

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that I intend to use across several sites.  However, I feel like it could be better tailored to suit my needs.

```
if($('#container > div:first').attr('id') === 'banner1') {
    // Do Something
} else {
    // Do Nothing
}
```

My Problem is- `'banner1'`  is actually `'bannerGallery'`, `'bannerLarge'` across different domains, this is due to shared projects and people working differently.

Instead of using 3 separate bits of code looking for 3 separate ID's.  Could I just search for the first div inside #container that has an ID containing 'banner'  which would then target all 3?

I've tried this, but it always runs the first function regardless of what the first Divs ID is.

```
if($("#container > div:first[id*='banner']")) {
        // Do Something
    } else {
        // Do Nothing
    }
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: `$(...)` returns a jQuery object so it's always truthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [*startsWith*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) attribute selector in combination with jQuery's **[`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** check:

```
// if the first DIV in #container has an id starting with "banner"
if( $('#container > div:first').is('[id^=banner]')) {
    ...
}
```

OR

```
// if the first DIV in #container has an id starting with "banner"
if( $('#container > div:first[id^=banner]').length) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
if( $('#container > div:first').attr('id').indexOf('banner') > -1) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div:first[id^='banner'])
```

it will show id which start with "banner"